# Issue with fetching query

Tags: php, mysql

Am trying to show a message if alert field is hidden and then updating that field so the message could not be shown again. Values are updating in db but the message is still being displayed can anyone help me finding out whats the issue.

```
<?php 
$alrt="hidden";
$checkalert=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_shift_test WHERE userid='$_SESSION[userid]' AND alert='$alrt' ");
if(!empty($checkalert)){ 
$updatealert=mysql_query("UPDATE user_shift_test SET alert='showed' WHERE userid='$_SESSION[userid]' ");
?>
<div class="alert" style="margin:10px;">
    Your shift is swapped.
</div><?php } ?>
```

Comment: did you start that *"you know what?"* - Edit: I guess you haven't which is probably why you deleted your question.

Comment: oh so now you undeleted, why? and did you start the session?

Comment: no i did not, i was trying something thats why i deleted my question but it did not work thats why i repost it.

Comment: consult http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php to see if anything comes of it.

Comment: yes i did
`<?php

include('db.php');
$page = "dashboard";

if(!($_SESSION['logged']))
 header("Location: login.php");
 
$user_details = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select * from users where userid = '$_SESSION[userid]'"));


?>`

Comment: Please, read up on [3-tier-architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) and start separating database calls, business logic and view layer (HTML / templates)!
Also, the [mysql extension](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) is deprecated, start using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)!

Comment: When people write with `mysql_` (deprecated in 2013, and no longer available in PHP7.0), there is 80% chance they also write code that is vulnerable to SQL injection. OK, maybe 90%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code:

- You use deprecated `mysql_` functions: these have not been maintained during the last 3 years and don't exist in PHP 7.xx. You should move to `mysqli_` or `PDO`;
- You inject strings inside your SQL statements. This could make you vulnerable to SQL injection. Use prepared statements instead;
- The test `!empty($checkalert)` will always be true, even if the result set is empty. It is a query object. This is the reason why the message keeps being shown (BTW: not *showed*);
- The *get-and-set* operation can better be done in one SQL operation, which will give you better performance. After the conditional update you can check if a record was updated, and if so, show the message;

Here is code for which you will first need to move to `mysqli_` functions (also for the connection):

```
<?php
// Perform update only if value is hidden
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,
    "UPDATE user_shift_test
     SET    alert = 'shown' 
     WHERE  userid = ?
     AND    coalesce(alert, 'hidden') = 'hidden' ");
if ($stmt) {
    // pass session variable as argument
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $_SESSION['userid']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    // check if any update was performed
    if (mysqli_stmt_affected_rows($stmt)) {
?>
        <div class="alert" style="margin:10px;">
            Your shift is swapped.
        </div>
<?php 
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: is there any way of doing it with mysql because its an old database am currently working on and its all code is on mysql. Not on mysqli

Comment: can i apply mysqli even if my connection file is on mysql ?

Comment: @S.MTalha, I would suggest you to take a look at `PDO` it's very simple to use and much more secure. (if used correctly ofcource).

Comment: You'll have to migrate away from `mysql_` sooner or later, as you will get into more problems. Take the opportunity now and migrate! It is not that much of work if you go to `mysqli_`, because the syntax is very similar (not the same though). But like sj03rs says, PDO is a good option: however, the migration may be a tad bit more work.